# Shea Nuts growing in South Africa

Tags: plant-care

What are the odds of getting shea nuts to grow in south africa? I am interested in growing shea nuts while living in South Africa.

Comment: From Wikipedia "full production is attained when the tree is about 20 to 30 years old".  You will have to have patience...

Answer (score 1):

A [zone 12 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitellaria) in what is [mostly zone 9-10](https://davisla.wordpress.com/plant-zones/africa-plant-hardiness-zones-map/)? I think you are looking for trouble, but there are parts of South Africa that hit zone 11.
How's your microclimate? If that's good, I'd give it a try, but be prepared for failure. Have you seen any Shea trees in your area?